# Are there any theories or traditions for dating how long after creation the Fall of Man occurred?

Tags: adam-and-eve, chronology, fall-of-man

Apologies if this question is too speculative.

The Bible does not explicitly state how long after Creation the Fall occurred. It can be argued to have occurred before the birth of Seth at the very latest (130 AM) as Seth was born after the killing of Abel and the original sin was presumably required for Cain to kill Abel, and it is virtually certain to have occurred before the Deluge 1656 years after creation. Are there any traditions or prominent theories which give a more precise date for the Fall after creation, either from Biblical or extra-Biblical sources? I also ask the more answerable question: do Christians believe that the Fall happened soon after Creation or after an extended period?

Comment: I guess this is not the answer you want, but between Genesis 4:1, 4:25 and 5:3, and given that it would be very odd if Cain did *not* inherit a sinful nature from Adam, 130 years is a pretty firm lower bound. IIUC however you want something more definite than that?

Answer (score 2):

According to Archbishop Ussher, Adam and Eve sinned on the tenth day of the first month.

Se https://answersingenesis.org/adam-and-eve/when-did-adam-and-eve-rebel/

His reasoning was that Day 6 was labeled good by God as was Day 7 (the first Sabbath), so the Fall could not be that early. Seth was born when Adam was 130 years old, so it must be before that.

The Day of Atonement is on the 10th day of the first month in the Jewish calnendar. When God slew an animal to make clothes for Adam and Eve to wear, that was the first sacrifice of atonement. Thus the bishop reasoned that Adam & Eve must have sinned on that day and God therefore commemorated it with the institution of the festival.

This is logical but speculative. We do not know.

People who have answered this question on other sites also mention the command to multiply. Adam and Eve would be disobeying God if they did not try to have children, so in their sinless state they would have obeyed. Since Cain was born after the expulsion from Eden, we must consider how long Adam and Eve could abstain from sexual relations and remain in a sinless state, or how long two completely healthy people could have relations before the woman conceived. It could not be that long, probably a few months at best.

Comment: ...although it seems to take a very long time for pre-Flood people to have firstborn children, which suggests either they *do* abstain for a long time (although that may be, as you note, a post-Fall thing), or for some reason it was quite hard to conceive back then. That said, I think this clearly satisfies the criteria for 'a theory or tradition', so +1.

Comment: If there is any chronology inherent in the early chapters of Genesis, Adam sinned before Eve bore Cain otherwise he would not have inherited a sin nature so Seth need not even be in the picture. +1

Answer (score -2):

It would depend on when you believe creation occurred. There are many Theistic Evolutionists out here (like me) that believe creation occurred billions of years ago.
That does not mean that we don't believe that Adam and Eve were historical figures, just that they weren't the first humans.

In my view, Adam was the first Israelite and first prophet, not the first human. He was to represent humanity in a covenant with God, but failed.
Eventually Jesus became the covenantal head of men and succeeded where Adam failed.

Anyway, billions of years between creation and Adam's fall.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Doesn't Abraham represent the generation of those eventually called Israel?